# how to set background Transparent with WindowChrome in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wfp which need:

1. remove the non-client frame from the window
2. be not included when recording screen
3. set window background transparent

When I set window with WindowStyle.None, it fails when calling SetWindowDisplayAffinity to exclude it from being recorded. So I customize the window with WindowChrome. It works well, but the window background is black when I set it transparent.

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="Transparent"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="50" Width="400">

    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome x:Name="Chrome" 
                  GlassFrameThickness="0" 
                  ResizeBorderThickness="0" 
                  CaptionHeight="0"/> </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    </Window>
```

Anything wrong? Or are there other ways to realize such requirements?

Comment: "it fails when calling SetWindowDisplayAffinity to exclude it from being recorded" can you please explain more about it.

Comment: I have a solution for it, but it requires WindowStyle.None, because in order to set AllowsTransparency="True" we have to set WindowStyle to None

Comment: @YoushaBinArif It means SetWindowDisplayAffinity(handle, WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE) fails when the parameter "handle" is  the  WindowStyle.None window handle. So setting WindowStyle.None is not feasible in this case.

Comment: oh okay, that make sense